# algorithm-coin changing code mistake

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, coin-change

Given a value N, if we want to make change for N cents, and we have infinite supply of each of S = { S1, S2, .. , Sm} valued coins, how many ways can we make the change? The order of coins doesn’t matter.

I have written below code but it is always returning one less than the actual answer. I want to know if this is the right way of coding up the solution?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ways=0;
int remember[100] = {0};

void foo(int coin_denomination[], int size, int sum)
{
    int i;
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    if (sum==0) {
        ways++; 
        return; 
    }   
    if (remember[sum]==1)
        return; 
    remember[sum] = 1;
    if (sum < 0)
        return; 
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        foo(coin_denomination, size, sum-coin_denomination[i]);
}

int main()
{
    int coin_denomination[] = {1, 2, 3}; 
    int sum = 5;

    foo(coin_denomination, sizeof(coin_denomination)/sizeof(coin_denomination[0]), sum);
    printf("%d\n", ways);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You say it always returns one less than the actual answer: maybe you need more test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some change to `foo` method. Your problem is that with the variable `remember` you are not counting some solutions. The goal of variable `remember` is not correct, you are using for not processing the same **coin collection** multiple times but you are saving only the **sum of the coin collection** and the sum could be obtained with multiple coin collections (ex: `1 1 1` have same sum that `1 2` when you select the second, `remember[3]` would be 1 and not be passing this point, missing solution `1 2 2`)

Other way of not repeating `coin collection` is needed, in this case, adding a parameter that represent the index of `coin_denomination` that is processing and only allow processing of coin after, the problem is solve.

Code (Tested with GCC 4.9.0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ways=0;

void foo(int coin_denomination[], int size, int sum, int coin_idx = 0)
{
    if (sum < 0)
        return;
    int i;
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    if (sum==0) {
        ways++; 
        return; 
    }   
    for(i=coin_idx;i<size;i++)
        foo(coin_denomination, size, sum-coin_denomination[i], i);
}

int main()
{
    int coin_denomination[] = {1, 2, 3}; 
    int sum = 5;

    foo(coin_denomination, sizeof(coin_denomination)/sizeof(coin_denomination[0]), sum);
    printf("%d\n", ways);
    return 0;
}
```